# internal server error in subdomains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I installed worpress to my main domain abcd.com. My addon domain name is fghi.com, when i try to access any worng page form addon domain for example fghi.com/fdsf i see internal server error.

I am using .htaccess file in root directory of wordpress installation. Here is code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

anybody know the correct solution?

Comment: By "add-on", you mean a domain pointed to a sub-folder of abcd.com? Or do you mean a domain that's also parked at the same folder as abcd.com? I assume it's the latter based on your phrasing, but I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can't be successfully accessed from your secondary domain because the Wordpress installation site url is set to one address. In your case, Wordpress recognizes "abcd.com" as the site url, and therefore any other url, even though it may point to the correct folder, will cause an internal service error